# is that true for any prime number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

if $p$ is prime, then there must exist a prime number of this form $N=Kp+1$, where $1 \leq K \leq p-1$ ?

I don't know if this proven, or if there any counterexample for this conjecture, but I checked the first 100000 prime numbers, and I got no counterexample, so, does any on have a proof, or counterexample ?

Comment: Without the restriction on $K$, this follows from Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions.

Comment: @lhf you mean that there is a theorem that says, if $p$ is a prime number, then there must exist a prime number of this form $N=Kp+1$, but this theorem does not put any restrictions on $K$, right ?

Comment: If there were such a prime $N$ then $N < p^2$.  The existence of such a prime $N$ is still unproved in general, but there is progress in that direction. Read about Linnik's theorem, e.g., at https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/teaching/613-Winter2011/LinnikTheorem.pdf.

Comment: @KCd thank you sir, for this paper

Comment: @KCd thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the restriction on $K$, this follows from [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

With the restriction $1 \leq K \leq p-1$, then $N < p^2$. It is currently unknown whether for every prime $p$ there is a prime $N$ less than $p^2$ that is congruent to $1\pmod p$. The best bound is currently $N < p^{5.2}$. See [Linnik's theorem](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/teaching/613-Winter2011/LinnikTheorem.pdf).

Comment: wonderful answer, thank you sir

Comment: Please don't assume that people on this site must be male. Defaulting to male pronouns or forms of address simply reinforces the bias against women in mathematics and contributes to their feeling unwelcome here.

Comment: @GregMartin I didn't mean that, I just wanna be polite, but thank you for this advice 